# calling QMetaObject::invokeMethod() with variable amount of parameters

Tags: c++, qt

I´m porting FitNesse´s Slim-server at the moment and I´m kinda stuck right now.
What I´m getting are strings like these:

```
("id_4", "call", "id", "setNumerator", "20")
("id_5", "call", "id", "setSomethingElse", "10", "8")
```

Where "setNumerator" and "setSomethingElse" are the names of methods that should be invoked and "20","10" and "8" are the arguments that I´m passing.
So my problem right now ist, I don´t know how to use **one** call to invokeMethod for both methods. My current workaround looks like this:

```
//(if instructionLength==5)
metaObj->invokeMethod(className, methodName.toAscii().constData(), Qt::DirectConnection,
                                          Q_ARG(QVariant, instructions.at(index).at(4)))

//(if instructionLength==6)
metaObj->invokeMethod(className, methodName.toAscii().constData(), Qt::DirectConnection, Q_RETURN_ARG(QVariant, retArg),
                                          Q_ARG(QVariant, instructions.at(index).at(4)),
                                          Q_ARG(QVariant, instructions.at(index).at(5)))
```

and so on...
So on the one hand, it seems that every invokeMethod-call needs very specific information, which makes it hard to do it with a variable amount of arguments. On the other hand, there has to be a way so I don´t have to do the same thing two(or later: ten) times.
So the question is, is there another way to do it with one call?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you look at the function definition, you'll see there is just one version :

```
bool QMetaObject::invokeMethod ( QObject * obj, const char * member, QGenericArgument val0 
    = QGenericArgument( 0 ), QGenericArgument val1 = QGenericArgument(), QGenericArgument 
    val2 = QGenericArgument(), QGenericArgument val3 = QGenericArgument(), 
    QGenericArgument val4 = QGenericArgument(), QGenericArgument val5 = 
    QGenericArgument(), QGenericArgument val6 = QGenericArgument(), QGenericArgument val7 
    = QGenericArgument(), QGenericArgument val8 = QGenericArgument(), QGenericArgument 
    val9 = QGenericArgument() )
```

In your case, this is what I would do :

```
QGenericArgument argumentTable[ 10 ];

... Fill up your data

QMetaObject::invokeMethod( objet, functionName, argumentTable[ 0 ], argumentTable[ 1 ],
    argumentTable[ 2 ], ... argumentTable[ 9 ] );
```

The arguments you don't use will be default initialized, which is the default behavior

Comment: It seemed to work at first, but it doesn´t.
It tries to invoke the right method with the right argument, but it fails.
for example: AddFixture::setSummand1(QVariant) normally works, but now it doesn´t

Comment: The problem was that I converted the methodName-String toLower, so the names didn´t match.
But now it works, so thank you.